# Fedora 35: Installing Nvidia drivers that allow to update the OS

Tags: fedora, drivers, nvidia

I know there are plenty of tutorials addressing this: such as [this](https://itsfoss.com/install-nvidia-drivers-fedora/) or [this](https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-graphic-drivers-on-fedora-35-gnome-41/).

I'd like to confirm those tutorials are correct, and that when there is an update for the OS, there won't be trouble with the Nvidia drivers. In the past, when there was an OS update that I tried to do, my screen would go black because the Nvidia drivers did not seem to be detecting the OS had been updated.

I apologize if this question is too simple, but I just want to make sure I am installing the drivers correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those tutorials are using `akmod`, which apparently is Fedora's system of automating the recompilation of third-party kernel modules whenever needed.

So whenever you get an OS update that provides a new Linux kernel, the `kernel-devel` package should also get updated, and once the new kernel and its corresponding `kernel-devel` package are both present, then `akmod` should be able to automatically (re)build the Nvidia driver for that specific kernel version for you.

Fedora 35 uses Linux kernel version 5.14.x (with the .x patch level increasing as necessary to fix bugs as they are discovered), and the Nvidia driver version in the packages suggested by the tutorials should be fine for it.

But if Fedora ever needs to upgrade the kernel version to 5.15 or above, maybe because there turns out to be a tricky security exploit for which there is no easily backportable fix, then you'll need to pay special attention to the driver rebuild process. Since you may be upgrading to a newer kernel release (main release, not just the patch level) than the newest that existed at the time those Nvidia drivers were packaged, the automatic rebuild might fail.

In that case, you would have to:

1.) uninstall the kernel version for which the driver rebuild failed *before you reboot after the failed upgrade*

2.) wait a day or two before retrying the update, so that the Nvidia driver packager will have time to build a newer version of the drivers, then

3.) update the Nvidia driver packages first, then the kernel.

It's unlikely that this happens, as I understand Fedora 35 is going to stay with kernel version 5.14 unless there are really major reasons to upgrade, but you should know what to do if it turns out to be necessary anyway.

Updating from Fedora 35 to a future Fedora 36 or higher will then be another challenge. You should delay the update until there are appropriate Nvidia drivers available for the new release of the OS distribution, preferably from the same source. In other words, if you use Nvidia drivers packaged by RPMFusion on Fedora 35, you should delay updating to Fedora 36 until RPMFusion has known-working Nvidia drivers for Fedora 36 too. That should allow for upgrade with a minimum of fuss.

Also, when using third-party drivers like Nvidia's, you should learn the basics of the text-mode console, so you won't be completely helpless if there's a problem with the graphics drivers.

Always make sure your boot menu has one or two previous kernel patch levels available, so that you can easily go back one or two kernel patch levels if there is a problem with the newest one. (Usually this will happen automatically, but be aware of it.)